# Retrieving Windows Form properties during multithreading

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I am somewhat familiar with VB.NET but am very new to multi-threading.

I have a situation in which I have started a new thread separate from the main process, and with that new thread I have created and displayed a new form. One of the methods in the new form's Load() procedure is to set the form's location, dependent on the main form (Form1's) location.

I am finding, however, that when I refer to Form1's properties from this thread, they are not being accurately retrieved. In particular, the Location.X and Location.Y properties appear as 0, when they are in actuality more substantial integers.

```
Private Sub SetLocation()

    Dim parentx, parenty, parentw, parenth As Integer
    Dim parentForm As Form = My.Forms.Form1

    parentx = parentForm.Location.X
    parenty = parentForm.Location.Y

    parentw = parentForm.Width
    parenth = parentForm.Height

    Me.Location = New Point(parentx + (parentw / 2), parenty + (parenth / 2))

End Sub
```

The part I find the strangest about this is that when I set a breakpoint within this SetLocation() method, and the program breaks for debugging, the X and Y variables will first register as 0 in the value display:

[x and y zero values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEpM1.png)

But then, while I'm debugging, if I access the information about Form1 in the IDE in its paused state, without resuming the application, and then return to viewing the X and Y values, the properties will eventually display as their actual values.

[x and y actual values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDllr.png)

Is it normal for form properties to be loaded in the midst of a debugging break point? Is this phenomenon a known aspect of multithreading in VB.NET? And will I have to go through much more complicated thread-communication methods in order for my new thread to access this information?

Thank you!

Comment: My.Forms.Form1 isn't what you think it is. It's the form model not the instance. You would need to declare Form1 somewhere or pass it forward to the thread.

Comment: You say, "I have started a new thread separate from the main process, and with that new thread I have created and displayed a new form", but that's bad. You should only ever use the main thread for creating UI elements. Only use threads when working with non-UI data.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am using a thread to display a loading screen while data loads on another thread. I know it is technically a UI element, but isn't that one of the uses for threading?

Comment: @Trevor My SetLocation() method works when I load this form from the main process, even using My.Forms.Form1 to access the form's properties. Can you explain why it would work from the main process and not from a thread?

Comment: @Marisha - No, you should not do anything with UI unless it's on the main UI thread. It's very difficult to get it right. If you're loading data you can do that on another thread perfectly fine. Why make your life difficult by also trying to multi-thread your UI?

Comment: Marisha, the My.Forms.Form1 property is accessing what is termed a default instance of Form1.  These default instances are created as part of VB's Application Framework, see: [My.Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379610(v=vs.80).aspx#vbmy_topic3) for some details and reason for their existence.  Due to the way these default Form instances are defined, a unique default instance is instantiated for each thread that accesses the property.  This thread affinity is one of many reasons to avoid their use.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thank you, that helps explain the situation quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to explain but I will do my best.

In your usage Form1 is the Form Class type, NOT the form itself.

**This is a common and ongoing confusion in VB.NET.**

```
  My.Forms
```

Lists only the form designs you have defined in the project... **NOT THE ACTIVE FORMS THEMSELF.**

If your project starts with Form1, VB.NET creates an **INSTANCE** of that form which **has it's own identity and memory allocation.**

When you open a new form that references the initial form, **you need to pass that identity** to the second form by reference.

The best way to do that, IMHO is to **augment Form2's constructor.** As Follows.

```
Public Sub New(owner_Form As Form1)
    Owner = owner_Form
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

End Sub
```

Then in your SetLocation code use the following

```
    parentx = Owner.Location.X
    parenty = Owner.Location.Y
    parentw = Owner.Width
    parenth = Owner.Height
```

**NOW:** your example code does not indicate where the thread is that starts the new form.

If the thread code is part of the Form1 Class you can simply do the following in your thread code.

```
Dim Form2 as New Form2(me)
```

If it is deeper than that, you would need to pass the Me down through the hierarchy.

**If your application is not overly complicated,** an Alternative Method is to use some other Global or shared Class Reference to identify the main form.

Example:

In a Global Module add

```
Public Main_Form as Form1
```

And in **Form1_Load** add

```
Main_Form = Me
```

Then in your SetLocation code use the following

```
    parentx = Main_Form.Location.X
    parenty = Main_Form.Location.Y
    parentw = Main_Form.Width
    parenth = Main_Form.Height
```

**WHY IS IT SO COMPLICATED**

What you have to force yourself to remember is that during execution your program can create any number of Form1s, or any other form for that matter. **Each one has it's own identity.**

My.Forms only lists the prototype.

**CROSS-THREADED UI REFERENCING**

As Enigmativity mentions, referencing the UI from a non UI-Thread can be a dangerous place to go and is fraught with issues that will drive you batty. I do agree usage of the UI through another thread is treading on very thin ice, however there are occasions, if the model is fully understood, that such referencing is acceptable. Read-Only usage like the current example being a case in point.

**However,** this "answer" would be the same whether the second form was started from a new thread or simply spawned as a normal Form.Show() from the initial form

**PS:** You could also simplify our code

```
Me.Location = <whatever method you choose>.Location
Me.Size = <whatever method you choose>.Size
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I think I understand the structure of passing Form1's object reference rather than just accessing Form1's class, so I think I have the tools to implement that if I need to. I do want to understand how this works as thoroughly as possible though, and I still don't quite understand what I was seeing during the debugging break (where the values were first 0 and then changed shortly after, during the same pause). Why was that occurring, and why doesn't it occur when I stay on the main process thread?

Comment: Who knows.. the IDE does some odd things sometimes.  I have never really figured out where the start form is REALLY defined.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Hey @Trevor, I have another related question, can you help me with it? I have put the Loading Screen on the main thread, but I am having trouble centering it. Turns out that the form's Location.X and Location.Y values are in screen coordinates, and the form's width and height values are in pixels. Do you know how to find these values in the same units so that I can place my loading screen in the center of Form1?

Comment: Hi @Marisha,  Screen coordinates are also in pixels, though the numbers may seem odd to you esp. if you have multi-screens. If you are using Owner like I showed you , you can usually use Me,left = Owner.left + (Owner.Width - Me.Width)/2, and similarly Me.Top = Owner.Top + (Owner.Height - Me.Height)/2 in the form's load method.

Comment: For some reason that is not working for me. Whether I use Location.X and Y, or whether I use Left and Top, the Loading Screen loads off-center: [image](http://i.imgur.com/erXpsND.png)

Comment: Look closer at my comment @Marisha, you are just adding in half the parent form... you need to add half the difference of the widths, heights)

Comment: Whoops, yeah, I found the error. Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you!